# Android: List not pass to RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, google-maps, android-volley

I'm passing a value from `MainActivity.class` to this fragment `ResultFrag.class`. In this class, it's supposed to display the places that is within the requested value from the user's current location.

The `json` return is correct.

I also tried to debug and display the item in the `myList` through Logcat and it is fine. So meaning that the `json` is parsed correctly and it's being added to the `myList`.

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getTheList());
```

This particular line that pass the list to the custom adapter; I don't think it's getting the list from the `getTheList()` method. Because I tried debugging using below codes by putting it in `onCreateView` but it's not logging anything:

```
 for (int b = 0; b < getTheList().size(); b++) {
        Log.d("list: ", Integer.toString(b) + " : " + getTheList().get(b).getPlace());
    }
```

Can anyone help? I've been working on this since yesterday.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class ResultFrag extends Fragment implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
double latitude, longitude;
String lat, lng;
private Bundle bundle;
private String data;
private static final String TAG_URL_DISTANCE = "///remove link///";
private static final String LOG_DISTANCE = ResultFrag.class.getSimpleName();
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<GetterSetter> myList = new ArrayList<>();
private static final String TAG = ResultFrag.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
Location location;
GoogleApiClient googleClient;


public ResultFrag() {

}

public void searchPlace(final String dist, final String latitude, final String longitude) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, TAG_URL_DISTANCE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(LOG_DISTANCE, response.toString());

            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                    GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
                    getterSetter.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                    getterSetter.setPlace(obj.getString("name"));
                    getterSetter.setDistance(obj.getInt("distance"));

                    myList.add(getterSetter);

                }
                for (int b = 0; b < getTheList().size(); b++) {
                    Log.d("list: ", Integer.toString(b) + " : " + getTheList().get(b).getPlace());
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "JSONException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(LOG_DISTANCE, "Volley Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("dist", dist);
            params.put("latitude", latitude);
            params.put("longitude", longitude);
            return params;
        }
    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_frag, container, false);

    bundle = this.getArguments();
    data = bundle.getString(MainActivity.option);

    if (checkGooglePlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleClient();
    }

    lat = getLatitude();
    lng = getLongitude();
    Log.d("radius", data);
    Log.d("latitude", lat);
    Log.d("longitude", lng);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), getTheList());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
   /* recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            })
    );*/
    return rootView;
}


private boolean checkGooglePlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            // Show error
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "No GPS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleClient() {
    googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (googleClient != null) {
        googleClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkGooglePlayServices();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleClient);
    searchPlace(data, getLatitude(), getLongitude());

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), getLatitude() + ", " + getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public List<GetterSetter> getTheList() {
    return myList;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return String.valueOf(latitude);
}

public String getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return String.valueOf(longitude);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    googleClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}
}
```

`MyAdapter.class`

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
List<GetterSetter> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Context context;

public MyAdapter (Context context, List<GetterSetter> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get event data
    GetterSetter current = data.get(position);

    holder.id.setText(current.getId());
    holder.place.setText(current.getPlace());
    holder.distance.setText("Distance: " + String.valueOf(current.getDistance()) + " km");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView id;
    TextView place;
    TextView distance;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeId);
        place = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should share the code of the MyAdapter class.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I added the MyAdapter class.

Comment: And the for b loop loes not log anything? How does `response` look like?

Comment: @HermannKlecker When the b loop is inside the `onCreateView`, it doesn't log anything. But when it's in the `searchPLace()` method, it does log something, meaning that the json parsing is working. It's just that it's not passing the list to the adapter initialised in the `onCreateView`.

Comment: The response return is correct as well. It's just that it's not passing the list to the adapter. I was thinking that it's got something to do with the modifier or something.. I'm not sure myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you fix it in the meantime? What I see is that you actually share the list between the adapter and the Fragment. And you make changes (add items) to the list after the adapter was constructed. But you do not call notfyDatasetChanged() on the adapter. Add that call once you are done with applyting changes to the list.

```
           JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
                getterSetter.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                getterSetter.setPlace(obj.getString("name"));
                getterSetter.setDistance(obj.getInt("distance"));

                myList.add(getterSetter);
            }
            myAdapter.notfyDatasetChanged()
```

Comment: After struggling a few days, I managed to solve it. I changed some of my codes and add the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method in my adapter instead. It's working now. Thanks. I'll just accept this as the answer :)